# How to generate Exception objects from Java Runtime Exception in Thirft IDL

Tags: java, thrift

The default exception declarations in Thrift IDL file generates Exception objects inherited from Java Exceptions class. How do I generate exceptions in Thrift IDL from Java RuntimeException class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I am heavily relying on thrift 0.8 in my code and I don't want put " throws MyException" all over the code.
I haven't found more ellegant way than to hack the compiler.